# How to display what is in a React JavaScript file, or rather a file to be interpreted by React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I hive tried several things and have see it work conceptionaly here [How to call and form a React.js function from HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38414139/how-to-call-and-form-a-react-js-function-from-html/38526630#38526630) All i get in my HTML generated from this file is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>


    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="description" content="BonApp">
    <meta name="keywords" content="HTML,CSS,JavaScript">
    <!-- <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;"> -->
    <link href="index.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,100,300,500,700,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.2.min.js" integrity="sha256-36cp2Co+/62rEAAYHLmRCPIych47CvdM+uTBJwSzWjI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.5.9/slick.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick-theme.css" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.2.1/react-with-addons.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.2.1/react-dom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.5.9/slick.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/t39.3284-6/13591530_1796350410598576_924751100_n.js"></script>
    <script src="https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/t39.3284-6/13591520_511026312439094_2118166596_n.js"></script>

    <title>BonApp</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="nav"></div>
  <div id="Gallery"></div>
  <div id="whatsnew"></div>
  <div id="advertiseApp"></div>
  <div id="events"></div>
  <div id="footer"></div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.autoplay').slick({
        slidesToShow: 2
        , slidesToScroll: 1
        , autoplay: true
        , autoplaySpeed: 2000
    , });
</script>

</html>
```

which is exactly what I have put into it, meaning it is not calling from the JavaScript file, (which is identical to the mentioned in the stack overflow message previously mentioned) I hope the answer falls within the range of: "I have the wrong version of Babel".

All help is appreciated!!!

EDIT: Here is a copy of the JS code just to be sure.

```
var NavBar = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      /* NavBar */
      <div className="dark_bg_color">
        <img src="logo.png" />
        <div className="table_center">
          <div>
            <ul>
              <li>daily specials</li>
              <li>gift gallery</li>
              <li>events</li>
              <li><i className="fa fa-search" />&nbsp;search</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="right_nav">
          <div className="table_center">
            <div>
              <button type="button">Sign Up</button>
              <button type="button">Log In</button>
              <div className="vertical-line">&nbsp;</div>
              <button type="button">Cart</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
ReactDOM.render(<NavBar />, document.getElementById('nav'));

var Gallery = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      /* Gallery */
      <div >
        <div align="middle">
          <div id="head">
            <img id="pic" align="middle" max-width="100%" src="title_pic.png" />
            <div align="left" className="big">
              <div>
                <span>Dine with the Best</span>
                <div className="words">
                  <span>BonApp connects you with limited-time, exclusive meals and events offered by the city’s best chefs.<br /><br /><br /><button type="button">JOIN BONAPP</button></span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
ReactDOM.render(<Gallery />, document.getElementById("Gallery"));

var WhatsNew = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div  className="dark_bg_color">
        <h2 style={{marginBottom: 30}}>
          <span>What's New</span>
        </h2>
        <div className="autoplay">
          <img src="whatsnew0.png" />
          <img src="whatsnew1.png" />
          <img src="whatsnew0.png" />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
ReactDOM.render(<WhatsNew />, document.getElementById("whatsnew"));

var BonEvents = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      /* Events */
      <div id="events" className="dark_bg_color">
        <div className="box">
          <div className="box-text">
            <div className="horizontal-line" />
            <div><div className="horizontal-line" /><p>LES BON CADEAUX</p></div>
            <div className="horizontal-line" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <h2>
          <span>Bon Events</span>
        </h2>
        <div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
ReactDOM.render(<BonEvents />, document.getElementById("events"));

var IOS = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    /* IOS */
    return (
      <div >
        <h2>
          <span />
        </h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
ReactDOM.render(<IOS />, document.getElementById("advertiseApp"));

var Footer = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      /* Footer */
      <div>
        <div className="footer_center">
          <div>
            <ul>
              <li>ABOUT</li>
              <li>PRESS</li>
              <li>CONTACT</li>
              <li>SUPPORT</li>
              <li>BONAPP FOR RESTAURANTEURS</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="legal_center">
          <div>
            <ul>
              <li>Copyright © 2016 BonApp Dining Inc.</li>
              <li>Privacy Policy</li>
              <li>Legal</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
ReactDOM.render(<Footer />, document.getElementById("footer"));
```

EDIT 2:

React CLI Output:

```
"use strict";

var NavBar = React.createClass({
  displayName: "NavBar",

  render: function render() {
    return(
      /* NavBar */
      React.createElement(
        "div",
        { className: "dark_bg_color" },
        React.createElement("img", { src: "logo.png" }),
        React.createElement(
          "div",
          { className: "table_center" },
          React.createElement(
            "div",
            null,
            React.createElement(
              "ul",
              null,
              React.createElement(
                "li",
                null,
                "daily specials"
              ),
              React.createElement(
                "li",
                null,
                "gift gallery"
              ),
              React.createElement(
                "li",
                null,
                "events"
              ),
              React.createElement(
                "li",
                null,
                React.createElement("i", { className: "fa fa-search" }),
                " search"
              )
            )
          )
        ),
        React.createElement(
          "div",
          { className: "right_nav" },
          React.createElement(
            "div",
            { className: "table_center" },
            React.createElement(
              "div",
              null,
              React.createElement(
                "button",
                { type: "button" },
                "Sign Up"
              ),
              React.createElement(
                "button",
                { type: "button" },
                "Log In"
              ),
              React.createElement(
                "div",
                { className: "vertical-line" },
                " "
              ),
              React.createElement(
                "button",
                { type: "button" },
                "Cart"
              )
            )
          )
        )
      )
    );
  }
});
ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(NavBar, null), document.getElementById('nav'));

var Gallery = React.createClass({
  displayName: "Gallery",

  render: function render() {
    return(
      /* Gallery */
      React.createElement(
        "div",
        null,
        React.createElement(
          "div",
          { align: "middle" },
          React.createElement(
            "div",
            { id: "head" },
            React.createElement("img", { id: "pic", align: "middle", "max-width": "100%", src: "title_pic.png" }),
            React.createElement(
              "div",
              { align: "left", className: "big" },
              React.createElement(
                "div",
                null,
                React.createElement(
                  "span",
                  null,
                  "Dine with the Best"
                ),
                React.createElement(
                  "div",
                  { className: "words" },
                  React.createElement(
                    "span",
                    null,
                    "BonApp connects you with limited-time, exclusive meals and events offered by the city’s best chefs.",
                    React.createElement("br", null),
                    React.createElement("br", null),
                    React.createElement("br", null),
                    React.createElement(
                      "button",
                      { type: "button" },
                      "JOIN BONAPP"
                    )
                  )
                )
              )
            )
          )
        )
      )
    );
  }
});
ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(Gallery, null), document.getElementById("Gallery"));

var WhatsNew = React.createClass({
  displayName: "WhatsNew",

  render: function render() {
    return React.createElement(
      "div",
      { className: "dark_bg_color" },
      React.createElement(
        "h2",
        { style: { marginBottom: 30 } },
        React.createElement(
          "span",
          null,
          "What's New"
        )
      ),
      React.createElement(
        "div",
        { className: "autoplay" },
        React.createElement("img", { src: "whatsnew0.png" }),
        React.createElement("img", { src: "whatsnew1.png" }),
        React.createElement("img", { src: "whatsnew0.png" })
      )
    );
  }
});
ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(WhatsNew, null), document.getElementById("whatsnew"));

var BonEvents = React.createClass({
  displayName: "BonEvents",

  render: function render() {
    return(
      /* Events */
      React.createElement(
        "div",
        { id: "events", className: "dark_bg_color" },
        React.createElement(
          "div",
          { className: "box" },
          React.createElement(
            "div",
            { className: "box-text" },
            React.createElement("div", { className: "horizontal-line" }),
            React.createElement(
              "div",
              null,
              React.createElement("div", { className: "horizontal-line" }),
              React.createElement(
                "p",
                null,
                "LES BON CADEAUX"
              )
            ),
            React.createElement("div", { className: "horizontal-line" })
          )
        ),
        React.createElement(
          "h2",
          null,
          React.createElement(
            "span",
            null,
            "Bon Events"
          )
        ),
        React.createElement("div", null)
      )
    );
  }
});
ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(BonEvents, null), document.getElementById("events"));

var IOS = React.createClass({
  displayName: "IOS",

  render: function render() {
    /* IOS */
    return React.createElement(
      "div",
      null,
      React.createElement(
        "h2",
        null,
        React.createElement("span", null)
      )
    );
  }
});
ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(IOS, null), document.getElementById("advertiseApp"));

var Footer = React.createClass({
  displayName: "Footer",

  render: function render() {
    return(
      /* Footer */
      React.createElement(
        "div",
        null,
        React.createElement(
          "div",
          { className: "footer_center" },
          React.createElement(
            "div",
            null,
            React.createElement(
              "ul",
              null,
              React.createElement(
                "li",
                null,
                "ABOUT"
              ),
              React.createElement(
                "li",
                null,
                "PRESS"
              ),
              React.createElement(
                "li",
                null,
                "CONTACT"
              ),
              React.createElement(
                "li",
                null,
                "SUPPORT"
              ),
              React.createElement(
                "li",
                null,
                "BONAPP FOR RESTAURANTEURS"
              )
            )
          )
        ),
        React.createElement(
          "div",
          { className: "legal_center" },
          React.createElement(
            "div",
            null,
            React.createElement(
              "ul",
              null,
              React.createElement(
                "li",
                null,
                "Copyright © 2016 BonApp Dining Inc."
              ),
              React.createElement(
                "li",
                null,
                "Privacy Policy"
              ),
              React.createElement(
                "li",
                null,
                "Legal"
              )
            )
          )
        )
      )
    );
  }
});
ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(Footer, null), document.getElementById("footer"));
```

Comment: Maybe I'm just not seeing it, but where in the HTML markup are you including the Javascript code you listed above?

Comment: no, it is kept in its own, separate js file

Comment: The react file should be transpiled and included in a script tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for the client's browser to execute your javascript code, it has to be requested by the client's browser. That means putting a `<script>` tag in your HTML document to load the file, something like this:

```
<script src="https://example.com/my-react-code.js"></script>
```

Without that, your code is just sitting on your server doing nothing.

But there's another step first: as @Vijay noted in the comments, your code needs to be transpiled. What does that mean? Well, look at your code: it's written in EcmaScript 2015, a recent dialect of Javascript that is not well supported by browsers. In order to ensure that your code works on most browsers, you need to translate it from the new dialect to something that browsers will be able to execute. This is called **transpiling**. [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) is one package that can do this; there are others as well. If you decide to use Babel, have a look at the [setup page](https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/) which gives detailed instructions on how to use Babel in a wide variety of different environments.

**Edit**

How to use Babel to transpile your code is a big question. I'll give a **very** brief example.

So imagine that you have the code given above saved in a file called `src/my-react-code.js` and you want to transpile it to a new file called `dist/my-react-code.js`. Imagine also that you have installed Babel locally with `npm install --save-dev babel-cli`. To transpile the source file, do this:

```
./node_modules/.bin/babel src -d dist
```

This will take your source file, transpile it (ie. translate it from new ES2015 syntax to old Javascript syntax), and save the result in `dist/my-react-code.js`.

**However**, this will not work given just the information in this question & answer. There are a couple more things you need:

Your source file needs to import the React package with a line like `import React from 'react';` at the top; there may be other packages that need to be imported too.

Babel can be configured in a lot of different ways. You'll need to include some additional Babel plugins. Off the top of my head, I think you'll need to do `npm install --save-dev babel-preset-es2015 babel-preset-react babel-preset-stage-0`. These packages tell Babel what kind of source code to expect - in your case, it's ES2015 code with React components embedded in it (the stage-0 package includes a set of packages that are particular parts of the ES2015 standard). You'll also need to create a `.babelrc` configuration file containing:

```
{
    "presets": ["es2015", "react", "stage-0"]
}
```

This tells Babel which plugins to use.

This command-line usage of Babel is documented at https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/. Pick your environment from the buttons at the top - I selected the first one, CLI.

Once you have a successful transpilation, take a look at the difference between the original source code and the final code - you'll see that Babel adds a lot of boilerplate code, basically rewriting features that aren't available in most browsers using "old" Javascript.

As mentioned above, there are many ways to configure Babel. I've given the simplest, but also the most cumbersome. Every time you change your source code, you will need to re-transpile it so your server sends it to the client. There are many tools for bundling all your Javascript together (browserify, webpack, etc.), automating the build process (grunt, gulp, etc.), testing your code (mocha, jest, etc.). You should spend some time imagining what your ideal work flow and environment would be and see if you can put it together using these tools.

Comment: Would you mind giving a small example, because, when I use babel, I install it through npm, and the only notes on the installation page on how to use the compiler are `require("babel-core").transform("code", options);`, which is clearly JavaScript, does this mean that I have to use a script tag somewhere and if so, where?  I apologize for these relatively simple questions, however, I am new to web development as well as dyslexic, as a result, picking up new languages and formats can be difficult.

Comment: I would also like to note that in the example from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38414139/how-to-call-and-form-a-react-js-function-from-html/38526630#38526630 it was possible to get this data displayed while in different files, not using Babel or any other compiler that I could detect.

Comment: Regarding [the other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38526630/2008384): that code is being run in the context of SO's web page. I'm not a developer for SO, so I don't know how their Javascript works. I suspect they're loading the Babel polyfill, which is a package that will transpile your code "on the fly". I'll edit the answer to include some *very* brief notes on Babel.

Comment: Thank you I very much appreciate it, I really hate to use stack overflow so much, but I appreciate your time and patients.