# How can I use a constant from my Typescript in html?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, constants

In my Index.ts I am creating two constants  that I want to use in my html file.

index.ts:

```
import React from 'react';

console.log("Hello World!");

const enableDropping = (event: React.DragEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
  event.preventDefault();
}

const handleDrop = (event: React.DragEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
  const id = event.dataTransfer.getData('text');
  console.log(`Somebody dropped an element with id: ${id}`);
}
```

index.html:

```
<div class="drag" onDragOver={enableDropping} onDrop={handleDrop}>Drop</div>
```

But I get the error message:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: enableDropping is not defined at
> HTMLDivElement.ondragover

So somehow my constants are not recognized. The output "Hello World!" works.

Comment: if it is vanilla html, attributes are not in camelCase, but lowercase.
Also any reason why you don't want to do that inside of your JS file?

Comment: @Mähnenwolf Thank you, so you mean I should write it like this:  `class="drag" onDragOver=enableDropping onDrop=handleDrop`? Yes, its because I am working in a team, and they have already a TS file and I need to integrate it inside the file.

Comment: I am not sure if it is vanilla. I think it is just normal html.

Comment: I tried without the camelCase, but still the same error unfortunately

Comment: the attribute should be lowercase, not the function name.
And I would suggest to not handle javascript function inside HTML files, but inside of JavaScript itself. So check inside of javascript if the div activates any of those methods. you could use `addEventListener`

Comment: `ondragover="enableDropping()"`
What you wrote in your OP looks like JSX.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, why TS doesn't have same codeblock or same file, coz you can combine them. If you want treat it differently. You can attach a listener onto your typescript file directly using queryselector or i think you can use this approach, [How to call and form a React.js function from HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38414139/how-to-call-and-form-a-react-js-function-from-html)